# How to update nested dictionary value after comparing key to list item

Tags: python-3.x

I want to loop through *my_list* and comparing the list items to the **key** in *my_dict*. How do I update the nested **value** of `'0'` for each time an item in the *my_list* matches the *my_dict* **key**?

```
   my_list = [1102, 4611, 4624, 4634, 1102, 1102, 4611, 1102]
   my_dict = {'1102':{'count':0},'4611':{'count':0},'4624':{'count':0}}
            
   for item in my_list:
      if item in my_dict.keys():
       # count:0 +=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
my_list = [1102, 4611, 4624, 4634, 1102, 1102, 4611, 1102]
my_dict = {'1102':{'count':0},'4611':{'count':0},'4624':{'count':0}}
            
for item in my_list:
  if str(item) in my_dict.keys():
    my_dict[str(item)]['count'] += 1

print(my_dict)

# {'1102': {'count': 4}, '4611': {'count': 2}, '4624': {'count': 1}}
```

While using the `if` statement, don't forget to convert the `type` of the `item` from `int` to `str`